# Double row navigation bar in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7

I want to have two rows in my navigation bar instead of the usual one. The top row will display a navigation bar title, cancel, and a save button. The bottom one (right under it) will display some icons with text. I want to be able to use something like:

[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

to hide the bottom row when the user taps on the top row or scrolls down.

A bunch of apps like LinkedIn use this feature.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a better idea to use a toolbar just under the navigation bar as navigations bars get back buttons etc automatically. You can hide the toolbar like hiding any other ui component. Toolbars also get buttons.